# Onsen + pushPage + options.onTransitionEnd

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

I try to use the `options.onTransitionEnd` available on `pushPage()` because I would like to call a `$scope.init()` function inside the controller of the pushed page.

I saw that I can just pass ONLY an anonymous function to the `onTransitionEnd` option.

For example:

```
app.navi.pushPage('page.html', {onTransitionEnd: function(){ alert('ok') }  } );
```

There is instead a way to call a `$scope` function inside the controller of the pushed page?

Tks a lot. David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function in this way as long as the button is in `NavigatorController` scope:

`<ons-button ng-click="myNav.pushPage('page1.html', {onTransitionEnd: myFunction})">Push</ons-button>`

```
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('NavigatorController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myFunction = function () {
    console.log('onTransitionEnd');
  };
});
```

Check it here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/Gpzvqw

In any case, if what you want is to initialize the pushed page perhaps it's easier to use page events (only `pageinit` is available for Onsen UI 1.x): http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#Pagelifecycle

Of course, the pushed page's controller will run as well.

Comment: Tks a lot Fran! Good idea but I suppose in this way you call a function inside the (pesudo-parent) NavigatorController. I need instead to call a function inside the controller that manages the page1.html (in reference to your example).

Comment: You can use `document.addEventListener('pageinit', function($scope) { ... });` in `PageController` in that case.